# How to get Duration of captured video in android?

Tags: android

Using below code i captured Video,but how to get duration of captured video in android ?
and also when sometimes user discard video and record new video then get duration of new video .

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_VIDEO);
```

Comment: possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3936396/1012284

Comment: @PadmaKumar its not duplicate ,there are just Cursor and also not duration

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using cursor you can get duration and there are `duration` Column in Cursor and you can get as a string.

```
Cursor cursor = MediaStore.Video.query(getContentResolver(),data.getData(),
                new String[] { MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DURATION });
System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>"+cursor.getCount());
cursor.moveToFirst();

String duration = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("duration"));
```

Comment: 1)Above suggested is working for getting duration from recorded video.
2)But when i tried to retrieve the duration from gallery selected video it is throwing IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: I am using this solution, But i am getting error and Carsh my app

Answer (score 9):

I think the easiest way is:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(uriOfFile);
int duration = mp.getDuration();
mp.release();
/*convert millis to appropriate time*/
return String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration) - 
        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration))
    );
```

Comment: By uriOfFile, do you mean the file Path appended with `file://` prefix ?

Comment: Please don't create MediaPlayer instance just to get file length. There is a dedicated MediaMetadataRetriever class in android for this. More details available in the following answer: stackoverflow.com/a/33247728/1713920

Answer (score 0):

MediaPlayer is a heavy object. Use MediaMetadataRetriever instead

```
fun getMediaDurationMs(context: Context, fileUri: Uri): Int? {
    val mmr = MediaMetadataRetriever()
    mmr.setDataSource(context, fileUri)
    return mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION)?.toInt()
}
```