# Android How to get particular video file duration in mins?

Tags: android, video, duration

I am searching solution for an following question .

I am binding the video files which is available in the particular folder to list view . In that i have found the name, size , But i am failed to get an duration.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10883464/776244

Comment: @Samir Thanks .. i will give a try and let u know

Comment: @SamirMangroliya I am getting null pointer exception in following line  System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>"+cursor.getCount());