# How to check and limit length of a video in the app

Tags: android, ios

I have recently built an application where user could able to sell their used items. In my current design, I have limited my app to post a single app per product. However, I am getting complaints from the user with this limitations.

Now I am trying to add new features, one of them is a video support. I wonder how to check and limit a video with certain seconds. The instagram or Vime allows 15 and 5 sec video accordingly. I wonder how could I able to check the duration of the video?

Comment: Check this answer regarding Cursor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883349/how-to-get-duration-of-captured-video-in-android

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ricardo, that answers my problem.