# MP4 Video Last frame

Tags: android, mediametadataretriever

I'm trying to get last frame of mp4 video using MediaMetadataRetriever but it always return first Frame for short videos (like 3s long videos), it work fine for long videos. FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever also give same result.

```
      MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
      retriever.setDataSource(video);
      String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
      Bitmap frameAtTime = retriever.getFrameAtTime(Long.parseLong(time)*1000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
      mImage.setImageBitmap(frameAtTime);
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: From the description of getFrameAtTime function, it will return 0 if the constraints cannot be satisfied. Can you try using `int frame = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_FRAME_COUNT)` to retrieve the final frame of the video and then use `retriever.getFrameAtIndex(frame-1)` to get the frame? Should also always check that extractMetadata isn't returning null.

Comment: getFrameAtIndex : Call requires API level 28 (current min is 21). I know that getFrameAtTime takes microseconds, not milliseconds that's why i * by 1000

Comment: Dope. My mistake, I read that as conversion to ms. Can you verify that the metadata returns the correct length of the video? [Idk if this is any help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33247728/3508192), but it's another way to get the duration

Comment: ya the time is fine, as i said it work fine for long video the issue with short video

Comment: just checking. I'd try messing with the option param, like using `OPTION_NEXT_SYNC`?

Comment: tried all of them ..

Comment: It looks like the function may be bugged - found a [github issue](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever/issues/180#issuecomment-419792104) for FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever, which you mentioned also didn't work. Their suggestion is to pass a time a few ms before the time of the final frame. Best of luck.

Comment: @charliebeckwith thx for ur time :)