# How to get the duration of a MediaItem in AndroidX Media3?

Tags: android, android-media3

I am using the AndroidX Media3 Transformer to trim a video file, but I can't figure out how to get the duration of the video (without spinning up a player). An [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33247728/686385) suggested using `MediaMetadataRetriever`, but this is part of the old Media API; I feel like there must be an equivalent in the new API. (It is, after all, something that the player will need access to.)

I see that several of the format decoder classes implement a method `getDurationUs()`, which is defined in the [`SeekMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/media3/extractor/SeekMap#getDurationUs()) interface, which looked promising, but I can't see how to get to that from a [`MediaItem`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media3/common/MediaItem).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I would love to get rid of `MediaMetadataRetriever` but I need it to get duration and thumbnails.

Comment: @casolorz, no, I haven't found anything in the Media3 library as of yet.

Comment: [Media issues#76](https://github.com/androidx/media/issues/76) did not support yet.